# Server Collection cannot be empty - Windows Server AppFabric 1.1

Tags: appfabric, windows-server, appfabric-cache

I get this error when i use multiple `dataCacheClients`. Ive seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279038/appfabric-1-0-error-server-collection-cannot-be-empty) and [this msdn question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/velocity/thread/4916b243-28e4-4d7f-900e-ebe9d6ddea62) but at the time of AppFabric 1.0, multiple `dataCacheClients` were not possible. Microsoft added this feature in AppFabric 1.1 (see [changelog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh351389.aspx)), which I'm using currently. Any ideas on why I get this error? Here's my config file:

```
<configuration>
<configSections>

 <section name="dataCacheClients"
         type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientsSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core"
         allowLocation="true" 
         allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
</configSections>

<dataCacheClients>
<!--client 1 for caching-->
<dataCacheClient name="dataCacheClient1">
  <localCache isEnabled="false" sync="NotificationBased" objectCount="100000"/>
  <clientNotification pollInterval="5"/>
  <hosts>
    <host name="!2345623ghf1.fg.com" cachePort="22233"/>
  </hosts>
  <securityProperties mode="None" protectionLevel="None" />
  <transportProperties maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" channelInitializationTimeout="60000" receiveTimeout="900000"/>
</dataCacheClient>
<!-- client 2 for session -->
<dataCacheClient name="dataCacheClient2">
  <localCache isEnabled="false" sync="NotificationBased" objectCount="100000"/>
  <clientNotification pollInterval="5"/>
  <hosts>
    <host name="!2345623ghf2.fg.com" cachePort="22233"/>
  </hosts>
  <securityProperties mode="None" protectionLevel="None" />
  <transportProperties maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" channelInitializationTimeout="60000" receiveTimeout="900000"/>
</dataCacheClient>


</dataCacheClients>


<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
</compilation>

<sessionState
  mode="Custom"
  customProvider="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider"
         type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache"
         cacheName="default"
         dataCacheClientName="dataCacheClient2" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

**NOTE:**

I'm using the DLL's found in `.\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server`

More Error details :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to get it working. There were some rudimentary but stupid mistakes I committed. Hopefully someone with the same issues would be able to get some guidance on this by my answer. The mistakes I committed/how it was rectified :

---

**1) Check the DLL's CLR version**

**Always, I mean, always** check the version of the DLLs you're using to refer in your consuming client. The DLLs to look out for are :

- Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core.dll
- Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client.dll
- Microsoft.WindowsFabric.Common.dll
- Microsoft.WindowsFabric.Data.Common.dll
- Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache  (this was what was causing me problems - I had an older version added in my solution; there's no need to refer this, just having this DLL in the same folder as the `Caching.Core` and `Caching.Client` is enough)

A good (or rather fail-proof) way to get the latest DLLs is to [download & install Appfabric](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=15848) and get the DLLs from  `.\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1`, add it in a folder **inside** your project and refer it from there.

---

**2) `DataCacheFactory` must have a reference to what `dataCacheClient` its referring to**

Just like how `AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider` must contain a `dataCacheClientName` attribute to refer to a specific cluster put in `dataCacheClient`, `DataCacheFactory` init in code must also contain a reference to the `dataCacheClient` which is gonna take care of `caching` :

```
DataCacheFactory _factory = new DataCacheFactory(new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration("dataCacheClient1"))
```

---

Thanks to everyone who helped in solving this issue!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on one of our development machines and it was ultimately found to be installation of Windows Server AppFabric. My configuration was totally correct. The same configuration worked on all machines except one and once we un-installed Windows Server AppFabric from that machine and installed Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 version, the issue was resolved.

I'm also using AppFabric to store Asp.NET SessionState.